# using pyjs: web browser won't read data from a txt file

Tags: javascript, python

I made a game in python, and i'm trying to translate it into javascript using pyjs.
The game needs to read txt files to get data.

The problem is that the browser won't open the txt files:
"NotImplementedError: open is not implemented in browsers"

It looks like browsers don't like the python "open" function translated. I've never done any javascript before. Is there a solution to access data files with pyjs?
I only need to read them...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've never used `pyjs`, but it looks like during the translation to javascript if the `open` function is present it will produce this error (see [here](https://github.com/jaredly/pyjamas/blob/master/pyjs/src/pyjs/builtin/pyjslib.py#L1310)).

The simple solution for this would be to include all the data from your txt files in your actual script. Depending on how big your txt files are, this could get messy. It might be best to create a separate python file with all your text data, and then import it into your game. Like this:

`txtdata.py`

```
txtfile1 = '''
enemy level 1 hp 20
enemy level 6 hp 100
enemy level 9 hp 200
'''
```

`game.py`

```
from txtdata import txtfile1

print txtfile1
```